# Basic auth is not working properly using isomorphic-fetch in GET call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-fetch-api

Passing Authentication param properly in headers but it is get converted into `WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Realm"` in the response headers.

Below is my code snippet of get api call.

```
doGetAuthRaceReplay (url) {
    var param = this._doGetParam({  'credentials': 'include',
                                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                    'Authorization': "Basic " + window.btoa('uname+':'+password')});
    return fetch(url, param)
}

_doGetParam (headers) {
    var params = {
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: headers
    };
    return params;
}
```

I am getting error 401 after calling api. It is working fine from POSTMAN.

I have also tried it with normal jquery ajax call but still not able to get it.

```
 var username = "uname";
 var password = "pass";
 var url = 'My url';
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(json) {
     alert("Success", json);
 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
 },

headers: {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
'Authorization' : "Basic " + btoa(username+':'+password)}
'accept':'application/json'
},
type: 'GET',
contentType: 'json',
});
```

Still getting 401 error.